# Magento2 : Custom Category Attribute value Not Saving?

Tags: magento2, module, attributes, custom-attributes

I've create a module to add a custom attribute to my categories, however my code doesn't seem to be creating the attribute in my eav_attribute table, the field shows on my category pages but  it doesn't save the values?

Can anyone advise why this isn't working.

> /app/code/Auto/CategoryAttributes/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Autosmart\CategoryAttributes\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
private $eavSetupFactory;

/**
 *
 * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
 */
public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
{
    $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
}

public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
    $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        Category::ENTITY,
        'category_short_description',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Category Short Description',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 1,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'General Information',
        ]
    );
}
}
```

> /app/code/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="autosmart_additonal_content">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Autosmart Additonal Content</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="category_short_description">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Short Description</item>
                <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this working now :)

> /app/code/Auto/CategoryAttributes/Setup/InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Autosmart\CategoryAttributes\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        //Category Attribute Create Script
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY,
            'category_short_description',
            [
                'group' => 'autosmart_category_fields',
                'label' => 'Category Short Description',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 1,
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => false
            ]
        );

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

> /app/code/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<fieldset name="autosmart_category_fields">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Autosmart Additional Settings</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="category_short_description">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Short Description</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Hope this helps anyone else having issues :)

*EDIT -- Diff for the Lazy Web*

[image]

[image]

Comment: what did u change

Comment: I changed the two files mentioned above?

Comment: ok will use a diff tool then...

Comment: This worked!!! Thanks! I pretty much had all this code, but something was off in my InstallData.php. I actually got to display this on the frontend too!!

Comment: Has anyone tried in `M2.3.3`? It worked in my `2.3.0`, but value doesn't save in 2.3.3. Any idea?

Comment: In M2.3.3 the textarea is saving well, but the dropdown not saved, is there have any other procedures to save the dropdown values

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 change custom category attribute value

---

```
<?php
//increase the max execution time
@ini_set('max_execution_time', -1);
//memory_limit
@ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

include('app/bootstrap.php');

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');

$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

$categoryCollection = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

$categories = $categoryCollection->create();

$categories->addAttributeToSelect('*');

$categories->load();

if (count($categories) > 0):

        foreach($categories as $category):

            $catId = $category->getId();

                $category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->setStoreId(0)->load($catId);
                $CategoryName = $category->getName();

                $metaTitle = "Buy ".$CategoryName." from My Site";

                $category->setMetaTitle($metaTitle);

                $category->save();


        endforeach;
     else: echo "No Results";
    endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is little different for me.

Re-run installation of eavSetup because adding attribute was failing

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory')->create()->load($categoryId);    
$category->setCustomAttribute("test");
$category->getResource()->saveAttribute($category, 'custom_attribute');
```