# Category attribute is not being saved

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, category-attribute

I have two custom attributes for categories. The code for both is similar apart from the `attribute_code` but one is not being saved when trying to add a value in adminhtml.

That's the `UpgradeData.php` where I add the attribute that's not saved:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(Category::ENTITY, 'megamenu_side_block', [
    'type' => 'text',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'label' => 'Menu Side Block',
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => 1,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 1,
    'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
]);
```

That's the part of `category_form.xml` where I create the adminhtml field:

```
<field name="megamenu_side_block" template="ui/form/field" sortOrder="51" formElement="wysiwyg">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="settings" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons1" xsi:type="string">bold,italic,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,forecolor,backcolor,|,link,unlink,image,|,bullist,numlist,|,code
                    </item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons2" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons3" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_buttons4" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="theme_advanced_statusbar_location" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
                <item name="files_browser_window_url" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="height" xsi:type="string">250px</item>
                <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Megamenu Side Block</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
            <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">megamenu_side_block</item>
            <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

**What I already checked:**

- The attribute is added to the table `eav_attribute`
- When I debug into `\Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Category\Save::execute()` the value is there and after `$category->save()` I can still get the value with
  `$category->getMegamenuSideBlock()`
- I tried to add a value manually but it didn't work either it wasn't loaded in backend
- When I change `dataScope` in xml to the `attribute_code` that is working the other attribute value is loaded just fine

As I said before I have a second attribute that uses the same code as above (just with different `attribute_code`) and that is working perfectly fine.

I've already checked several posts here but I didn't see any difference to my code or it didn't work.

What could be the reason that it's not saved to the database? Am I missing something in my code?

**Update:**
As @Alex suggested I tested it within `98-magerun2 dev:console` but one is being saved properly into database the other one not.

[image: test with n98-magerun2 dev:console]

Comment: Try `n98-magerun2 dev:console` to isolate the problem (load category, change, save)

Comment: @Alex I tried it but it has the same result

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180757/magento2-custom-category-attribute-value-not-saving

Comment: I already had a look at this question. My difference in the UpgradeData is just that I leave `visible_on_front`. `sort_order` and `group` as default and set `user_defined`, `wysiwyg_enabled` and `is_html_allowed_on_front` to 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that the attribute was not added to a attribute group.

The following code solved the problem:

```
$attributeSet = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId(Category::ENTITY);
$attributeGroup = $eavSetup->getDefaultAttributeGroupId(Category::ENTITY);
$eavSetup->addAttributeToGroup(
    Category::ENTITY,
    $attributeSet,
    $attributeGroup,
    $eavSetup->getAttributeId(Category::ENTITY, 'megamenu_bottom_block')
)->addAttributeToGroup(
    Category::ENTITY,
    $attributeSet,
    $attributeGroup,
    $eavSetup->getAttributeId(Category::ENTITY, 'megamenu_side_block')
);
```

The code of both attributes was the same. I have no idea how `megamenu_bottom_block` was added to a group but by having a look in the database in `eav_entity_attribute` table I managed to find the only difference between the attributes in the database.

Answer (score 0):

> Use functions like below

```
 public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $attributeName = $this->getAttribute()->getName();
        $value = $object->getData($attributeName);

        if ($imageName = $this->getUploadedImageName($value)) {
            $object->setData($this->additionalData . $attributeName, $value);
            $object->setData($attributeName, $imageName);
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            $object->setData($attributeName, null);
        }
        return parent::beforeSave($object);
    }



public function afterSave($object)
    {
        $value = $object->getData($this->additionalData . $this->getAttribute()->getName());

     --Write your code--
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean I should write a plugin to save the attribute? But why my other attribute works just fine without a plugin and I would rather fix the actual problem instead of working around it

Comment: Interesting idea but very hacky :-/